# JPA doesn't wire entities after fetching from database

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa

I'm generating 5 entity classes but I'm going to show only 2 what have a sense.

**UserPersonal**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MP_USER_PERSONAL")
public class UserPersonal implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5681474541014032737L;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Collection<UserPersonalPhoneNumber> phoneNumbers;
    private User user;
    private Collection<Address> addresses;

    public UserPersonal() {
        phoneNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public UserPersonal(String firstName, String lastName, User user) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userPersonal", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public Collection<UserPersonalPhoneNumber> getPhoneNumbers() {
        return phoneNumbers;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumbers(Collection<UserPersonalPhoneNumber> phoneNumbers) {
        this.phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers;
    }

    @Id
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "EMAIL")
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userPersonal", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Collection<Address> getAddresses() {
        return addresses;
    }

    public void setAddresses(Collection<Address> addresses) {
        this.addresses = addresses;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserPersonal [firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", phoneNumbers=" + phoneNumbers
                + ", addresses =" + addresses + "]";
    }

}
```

**ADDRESS**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MP_USER_PERSONAL_ADDRESS", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"EMAIL", "CITY", "STREET", "HOUSE"})
})
public class Address implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1309109354717562031L;

    private long id;
    private String city;
    private String street;
    private String house;
    private UserPersonal userPersonal;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "ID")
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "CITY")
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    @Column(name = "STREET")
    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    @Column(name = "HOUSE")
    public String getHouse() {
        return house;
    }

    public void setHouse(String house) {
        this.house = house;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "EMAIL")
    public UserPersonal getUserPersonal() {
        return userPersonal;
    }

    public void setUserPersonal(UserPersonal userPersonal) {
        this.userPersonal = userPersonal;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Address [id=" + id + ", city=" + city + ", street=" + street + ", house=" + house + "]";
    }

}
```

after then i try to fetch entries by appropriate method

```
public void findUser() {
            UserPersonal user = em.find(UserPersonal.class, "3");
            logger.info("{}", user.toString());
            logger.info("{}", user.getAddresses().size());
        }
```

looking at the console, there is a select whereby hibernate does the request to the database and get the proper result, it look like:

```
mysql> select userperson0_.EMAIL as EMAIL3_1_0_, userperson0_.FIRST_NAME as FIRST_NA1_1_0_, userperson0_.LAST_NAME as LAST_NAM2_1_0_, addresses1_.EMAIL as EMAIL5_2_1_, addresses1_.ID as ID1_2_1_, addresses1_.ID as ID1_2_2_, addresses1_.CITY as CITY2_2_2_, addresses1_.HOUSE as HOUSE3_2_2_, addresses1_.STREET as STREET4_2_2_, addresses1_.EMAIL as EMAIL5_2_2_ from MP_USER_PERSONAL userperson0_ left outer join MP_USER_PERSONAL_ADDRESS addresses1_ on userperson0_.EMAIL=addresses1_.EMAIL where userperson0_.EMAIL='3';
+-------------+----------------+----------------+-------------+----------+----------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+
| EMAIL3_1_0_ | FIRST_NA1_1_0_ | LAST_NAM2_1_0_ | EMAIL5_2_1_ | ID1_2_1_ | ID1_2_2_ | CITY2_2_2_ | HOUSE3_2_2_ | STREET4_2_2_ | EMAIL5_2_2_ |
+-------------+----------------+----------------+-------------+----------+----------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+
| 3           | vova           | black          | 3           |        4 |        4 | kiev       | 10          | mira         | 3           |
+-------------+----------------+----------------+-------------+----------+----------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

finally logger return this result, where Addresses is absent and size = 0:

`UserPersonal [firstName=vova, lastName=black, phoneNumbers=[], addresses =[]]`

`0`

**Why? Where is error ?**

Comment: Only firstName and lastName are type of String.

Comment: what do you mean ? email String as well just wrote as 3 in example

Comment: Are you sure there are addresses associated to this UserPersonal/Email?  How did you add them?  Chances are likely that you are setting only one side of your relationship and not keeping the many side in synch with the change.  If so, the collection will always be empty until you refresh the entity.

Comment: I don't know what the problem. All schemes were generated by hibernate automatically. What I see  in logs of hibernate that hibernate does request to database. I checked that request manually in the mysql client and I posted result of it above. What about any wrong setting it's likely because i don't know what is error in this situation. Therefore ask for help.

Comment: if it can help then i didn't entities by hibernate only directly by db client